# CMD error different than error displayed in python

Tags: python

I have a function in python that runs some programs in the shell command.

```
def run_script(d,f):
    os.chdir (d)
    run_status = "\n-----Running %s.cmd"%(f) 
    print run_status 
    command = "bash ./%s.cmd  | tee %s_log.txt"%(f,f)      
    os.system(command)
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (out, err) = proc.communicate()
    print "program output:", out
```

Why does the error message varies when i run it from the python script and the cmd.

When i run it from the python script I get the following output:

```
-----Running create_bank.cmd
program output: **ESC**039588d0-51c2-4861-a4b6-9f4aa0f8492a
```

and if i run it form the cmd i get a more descriptive error message with two extra lines showing the error

```
X:\2010\iter0\skims>bash create_bank.cmd
Could not create Emme database 'emmebank'!
No Emme licence was found
←039588d0-51c2-4861-a4b6-9f4aa0f8492a
```

How can i modify my function so it is more descriptive as the cmd error message?

Comment: You've showed a script that does the same thing two different ways, both of which are attempts to use cmd.exe to run bash to run a .cmd file to do who knows what. Which one of this means "run it from the cmd" and which "run it from the python script"?

Comment: Also, are you running from the same working directory in both cases? Because it seems plausible that whatever your .cmd is, it's expecting to find a database file, license file, etc. in the working directory, and the error it's complaining about in the second version is caused by them not being there.

Comment: Finally, why are you running bash to run a .cmd file (which is basically a DOS batch file)? Why are you using the shell to run bash instead of just running it directly? Why are you using any shells at all here, much less three of them?

Comment: @abarnert I think the OP is getting the same error in both cases. If you look at the last line of output, the text is the same. The difference is the second case has two additional lines where as the first case does not. However, the answer here is likely that the first two lines are being written to ``stderr``, which you are not ``PIPE``'ing in your python version, but are instead redirecting into a file. Does the ``log.txt`` file contain the two missing lines?

Comment: No, just the output line from the program output.

Comment: @abarnert I just started a new job and this is how the have it setup, I'm not completely clear why they have been running it from the bash command line, but I'm sure they must have a reason. I'm just trying to identify the reason and the solution for the error message variation.

Comment: @aruisdante: I still don't even know what the "both cases" are; I'm having a hard time reading his mind here, and when he only answers one out of every five questions, I'll leave it to you to try to help…

Comment: @aruisdante using the stderr answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only print "out" but not "err", so you don't see the stderr output that you can see while running the script manually.

try:

```
print "program out:", out
print "program errors:", err
```

Comment: when i was witting the function the i wasn't using proc variable so i left it there. Ill remove it after this. Thank you